# How do I fix JS so the text isn't erased and continues to build up?

Tags: javascript, css

I like the idea of this code that creates a "typing effect" on my site, however I don't know how to edit JS very well. I'd like the text to be typed on but not be erased. I'd also like the cursor to remain blinking at the end.

I've fixed some of the CSS to my liking, but I've provided it in case it's necessary to complete the effect.

```
/***Javascript****/
<
script type = "text/javascript" >
    // function([string1, string2],target id,[color1,color2])
    consoleText(['Divi Notes.', 'Divi Tips and Tricks', 'Made with Love.'], 'text', ['#BD6983', 'tomato', 'lightblue']);

function consoleText(words, id, colors) {
    if (colors === undefined) colors = ['#fff'];
    var visible = true;
    var con = document.getElementById('console');
    var letterCount = 1;
    var x = 1;
    var waiting = false;
    var target = document.getElementById(id)
    target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
    window.setInterval(function() {

        if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var usedColor = colors.shift();
                colors.push(usedColor);
                var usedWord = words.shift();
                words.push(usedWord);
                x = 1;
                target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 1000)
        } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                x = -1;
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 1000)
        } else if (waiting === false) {
            target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
            letterCount += x;
        }
    }, 120)
    window.setInterval(function() {
        if (visible === true) {
            con.className = 'console-underscore hidden'
            visible = false;

        } else {
            con.className = 'console-underscore'

            visible = true;
        }
    }, 400)
} <
/script>
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khula:700); 

.hidden {
 opacity:0;
}
.console-container {
 font-family:Khula;
 font-size:4em;
 text-align:center;
 height:30px;
 width:600px;
 display:inline;
 position:relative;
 color:black;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin:auto;
}
.console-underscore {
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 left:10px;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .console-container {  font-size:2em; }
}
```

```html
<div class='console-container'><span id='text'></span><div class='console-underscore' id='console'>_</div></div>
```

Expected results above, current results can be seen here: https://divinotes.com/typing-text-effect-using-divi-code-modules/

Comment: Could you provide the HTML aswell? Would be easier to recreate your problem then.

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: I've added the HTML kasperluage, thanks for looking

CertainPerformance - I tried to fix the Javascript, is that more accurate? I'm far from a JS expert :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i get your idea ... but you can change the case witch is erasing the text.

```
else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                x = -1;
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 1000)
}
```

The second problem is that it only renders one word at a time... If you want to have more words in different colors at the same moment, you should not write into innerHTML of the target element... Instead create child Elements of that tag and change only the active one....

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    // function([string1, string2],target id,[color1,color2])
    consoleText(['Divi Notes.', 'Divi Tips and Tricks', 'Made with Love.'], 'text', ['#BD6983', 'tomato', 'lightblue']);

function consoleText(words, id, colors) {
    if (colors === undefined) colors = ['#fff'];
    var visible = true;
    var con = document.getElementById('console');
    var letterCount = 1;
    var x = 1;
    var waiting = false;
    var target = document.getElementById(id)
    var textElement = document.createElement('span'); //a variable to store the active one
    target.appendChild(textElement); // we append the textElement to the target
    textElement.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0]) //instead of modifying target we modify textElement
    window.setInterval(function() {

        if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            textElement.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var usedColor = colors.shift();
                colors.push(usedColor);
                var usedWord = words.shift();
                // You can remove the repeating by uncommenting the following line
                words.push(usedWord);
                x = 1;
                textElement.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 1000)
        } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) { // erase case
            waiting = true;
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                letterCount = 0; // start with a new word
                textElement.innerHTML += " "; // apend a space to the old one to get seperation
                textElement = document.createElement('span'); // create a new textElement for the next word
                target.appendChild(textElement); // and append the new element to the target
                waiting = false;
            }, 1000)
        } else if (waiting === false) {
            textElement.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
            letterCount += x;
        }
    }, 120)
    window.setInterval(function() {
        if (visible === true) {
            con.className = 'console-underscore hidden'
            visible = false;

        } else {
            con.className = 'console-underscore'

            visible = true;
        }
    }, 400)
} </script>
```

You can remove the repeating by uncommenting the following line
`words.push(usedWord);` This line adds the active word back to the words Queue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution! I'm not entirely sure what all of what you said means. This might be over my head a bit.

I don't need any of the text to be different colors, in fact I just want it all to be all black.

This will go in the hero section of my website, so I'd like it to look like this:

"Header Title
Line two will go under it

Comment: did you try my code and does it fit your purpose? the colors are managed in the following line ... Just change the color array to be `['black']`.
`consoleText(['Divi Notes.', 'Divi Tips and Tricks', 'Made with Love.'], 'text', ['black']);`

Comment: When you only want one word just uncomment the repeating and change the words array to only one word. 
EXAMPLE: 
```consoleText(['This is a loooong message'], 'text', ['black']);```

Comment: Thanks @buh13246 that is very close, however once it finishes all of the lines of text it just keeps repeating them.  Is there a way to get it to just pause at the end? Also any way to speed up the animation?

Thanks again!

here is what it looks like on my site: http://new.webink.design/

Comment: @SeanRowe I edited my post to fit this purpose (read the last part). The line you need to uncomment is near line 25

Comment: Wow you are incredible!  Last request.  I'd like line break so that each sentence is can be on a seperate line? Is that possible or does that make it way more complicated?

Comment: @SeanRowe I changed the following line to get seperate the words with a break (i dont like it because styling is way more efficient ... but it work...). Please replace line ~47 `textElement.innerHTML += " "; // apend a space to the old one to get seperation` with `target.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); // insert a break to get seperation`.
This was my first contribution to Stack Exchange. I would appreciate if you accept my answer.

Comment: I have a few more questions if you are willing, but you've been more than helpful already.

How do I make one of the lines bold and the others not?
Can I add <h1> or <h2> html tags onto certain lines?

Comment: @SeanRowe Yes you can just write html Code into your words like `['<h1>/WEBINK DESIGN</h1>', '<h2>SO MUCH MORE THAN JUST WEB DESIGN</h2>', 'BRANDING_MARKETING_SOCIAL MEDIA_SEO']`. But I dont know if this works in any browser, because in a certan moment the code of the textElement is something like `<h2>SO MUCH MORE THAN JUST WEB DESIGN<` which is not valid source code, instead you could change the code to be able to get a meta information about the type. But I think this is something you can do on your own after a little more js practice ; ).

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks again....for some reason my CSS no longer allows me to change the font. It's set to 'serif' now and I don't know how to switch it to something else.